# Hyphenation problems after a command in LuaLaTeX

Tags: macros, luatex, hyphenation

When working with LaTeXe commands integrated in German sentences many times a hyphen will be used. The problem is that this hyphen should always be a break point. LuaLaTeX unfortunately does not do that by default. To show what I mean:

[image: hyphenation not working]

as the LuaLaTeX output vs. the (correct) pdfLaTeX output:

[image: pdflatex is right]

That example would work the way I want it if you change the `-` after `\LaTeXe` or `\href{}{}` to e.g. a `\-` (then it breaks correctly).

*Question:* How to automatically (in the best case I do not want to change the input) convert a hyphen after a command into a hyphen which breaks, but stays if there's no break in LuaLaTeX?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test \LaTeXe-Dokument test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test te \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/}{\mbox{Wiki}}-Seite test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test Test-Dokument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, the fact that you use LuaLaTeX is crucial here -- the output would look different if pdfLaTeX were used.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a weird thing.  This is not happening neither wIth latex, nor with pdflatex, nor with xelatex.  It's only happening with lualatex.

Comment: @Mico I've added the tag. Do you know why it behaves this way?

Comment: To get a hard hyphen, i.e., one that will shown up both in the interior of a line and at the end, use the `babel` shorthand `"=`, not `"-`.

Comment: @TeXnician - I'm afraid I have no insights into why the behavior under LuaLaTeX is so different from that under pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Note that the difference here is because of the internal box constructions in `\LaTeX`, so it is not typical of a hyphenated normal word.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This also happens with the `\href` example (or in real life also with `\gls` etc.). Is that also some special box construction?

Comment: @TeXnician yes the link would show as "whatsit"  in the luatex manual description of `\hyphenationbounds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing `\hyphenationbounds`, 1 seems a good value in this case.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hyphenationbounds=1
\begin{document}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test \LaTeXe-Dokument test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test te \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/}{\mbox{Wiki}}-Seite test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test Test-Dokument
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does this mean? The luatex docs say "strict start", but what effect would a change have on e.g. a normal book that has only some of those constructions?

Comment: @TeXnician my answer is intentionally vague, I don't think anyone has really experimented to see the best settings of this parameter which controls whether luatex sees tex constructs as preventing hyphenation in the following or preceding text.  The `\hbox` in `\LaTeX` counts= as `hlist` in that description in the luatex manual.

Comment: Should this be reported somewhere else then? Or is LuaLaTeX just the wrong choice when it comes to such hyphenation problems?

Comment: @TeXnician there's nothing to report really, classic tex has a fixed heuristic for when it tries to hyphenate a string of letters and when it will skip to try the next word, luatex parametrises that in various ways which means that tweaking the parameters to get the best effect is expected. But `\LaTeX` is a very special case, presumably most documents do not have such a construct mid-sentence.

Comment: As I said, it happens also with `\href` and `\gls` constructions which I suspect some documents to use mid-sentence. But for now this seems to get rid off the main problem.